# Can C# can run code before or after main like in objective C

Tags: c#, objective-c, static-methods

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/objc-features_1.html#SEC2

The GNU Objective-C runtime provides a way that allows you to execute code before the execution of the program enters the main function. The code is executed on a per-class and a per-category basis, through a special class method +load.

Update: the answers I read below are not satisfactory. There's nothing special to call a function from a main program. The question is about HOOKING the SYSTEM that is the SYSTEM calls a function without YOUR PROGRAM even aware of it at RUNTIME.

Instead of Objective C see this article on Visual C++ (thanks to stackoverflow guy who answer my previous question):
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/threadsprocesses/article.php/c6945

Otherwise there was no need for Objective C Runtime to include this load method. main entry point of course exists for Objective C program and if it suffices to just call a static method WITHIN the main method there's no big deal :)

Comment: Actually, there *was* no need for the GNU Objective-C runtime to include the load method.  It doesn't exist in the Apple version of Cocoa.  Why exactly do you think you need it?

Comment: Let's say I want to create a container for a class of applications, I don't want the applications to be aware of any plumbings like some system variables I would setup, or anything else It's just to give an example.

Comment: The load method most certainly does exist in Cocoa, and always has (since 10.0, anyway).  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418815-load?language=objc

Answer (score 6):

In OOP languages since main is always inside a class, there is always a way to run some code before main function is executed. In Java it's called [static initialization block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). A similar mechanism is also available in C#. [See this link](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html#staticconstructor)

Code example:

```
namespace CSharpConsoleTest
{
  class Program
  {
    static Program()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test123");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test111");
    }
  }
}
```

Well the point is to be able to initialize static variables inside the class since they are created before instance variables.

Answer (score -1):

What your are looking for in c# are called class constructors(runs before) and class destructors(runs after)

Here is a link to a tutorial...

http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/constructors-and-destructors/